# What data I will get in global $user; used in hook_node_update when drupal 7 cron executes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have implemented `hook_node_update` in a module. I can access loggedin user data by defining global user object `global $user;`. I need to know **loggedin** user and **content creator** so that I process some instructions.

The **question** is that if a node is scheduled to **unpublished** and when drupal runs cron what I will get in `global $user;`? The same user who made a change in node or something else? Is there any way to access data of user who last updated this node?

**Update:**

I think I was failed to explain what I need. Consider this scenario.

There are two users, A and B. A created a content (node) say `Example`. When B changes something in `Example` I need to send an email notification to A. So when this `Example` content is scheduled to be archived by user B, this cron task is saved and will be executed by cron. When cron runs, at that point how I can know that this is scheduled by B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property in `$node` object that has user id who last updated a node.

`$node->revision_uid`

Answer (score 1):

The global [`$user`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) object is always:

> An object representing the user currently visiting the site.

That can be either an authenticated user, or the anonymous user (uid=0) if applicable.

So if a user creates/edits a node through the UI, and you implement`hook_node_update()`, the `$user` object will be that of the user responsible for creating the content, as you expect.

Drupal runs cron as the anonymous user, it doesn't create a session based on unrelated contextual data like the user ID attached to an arbitrary node - such a workflow wouldn't make sense.

To get the user object from a node object, you can simply use [`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7):

```
$account = user_load($node->uid);
```

Comment: Can't you just inspect `$node->original->uid` to get that info?

Comment: This gives me content author id.

Comment: It'll give you the original author ID, as in the "outgoing" author ID. `$node->uid` will give you the ID of the new author. Is that not what you're looking for?